# Adding Finite State Transducer (FST) in XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

Hi I am trying to add a Finite state transducer in the paper, which look like this 
[image]

Using  `tikz`  library. I don't understand how it works.

The code I am working on

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\malayalam}{Meera}
\newfontfamily{\kannada}{Kedage Normal}
\begin{document}


digraph finite_state_machine {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"

    node [shape = doublecircle, label="{f}", fontsize=12] f;
    node [shape = doublecircle, label="{q2, f}", fontsize=10] q2f;

    node [shape = circle, label="S", fontsize=14] S;
    node [shape = circle, label="{q1}", fontsize=12] q1;
    node [shape = circle, label="{q2}", fontsize=12] q2;

    node [shape = point ]; qi
    qi -> S;

    S   -> q1  [ label = "a" ];
    S   -> q2f [ label = "b" ];
    S   -> q2  [ label = "c" ];

    q1  -> q2  [ label = "b" ];

    q2f -> f   [ label = "b" ];
    q2f -> q2  [ label = "c" ];

    q2  -> f   [ label = "b" ];
    q2  -> q2  [ label = "c" ];
}
\end {document}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question a little to use the subject of your other question and tidied up the content a little. You can roll my edit back if you find it unhelpful but I would not, personally, know what 'FST' meant so I think having it spelt out is good. (And you wouldn't be asking if you didn't want help, I assume, so it isn't necessary to explicitly mention that. Maybe put 'No help!' if you ever don't want answers!) Anyway, I think this is clearer but do roll back if not.

Comment: Sorry,  Your are right. The way I ask help is messy, lack of experience.

Comment: Sorry. Did you mean to make the image invisible again?

Comment: No, I need to show the image as a model

Comment: OK. Good. It reappeared. Can you complete the code so we can compile it? For example, it would be good to know which TikZ library defines `digraph finite_state_machine`.

Comment: @cfr. I am sorry. I have no idea. How these labels are produced. Any example that represents a simple Finite state Transducer would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version done in TikZ. Next time, please post some code which is relevant to the what you want to do! It is rather confusing to have code which seems to have nothing to do with the question.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      initial/.style={line width=1pt},
      accepting by double/.append style={line width=1pt},
      semithick,
    ]
    \node (0) [state, initial] {$0$};
    \node (1) [state, above right=of 0] {$1$};
    \node (2) [state, right=of 1] {$2$};
    \node (3) [state, right=of 2] {$3$};
    \node (5) [state, below right=of 0] {$5$};
    \node (6) [state, right=of 5] {$6$};
    \node (7) [state, right=of 6] {$7$};
    \node (4) [state, below right=of 3, accepting] {$4$};
    \path [-{Stealth[]}]
      (0) edge node [above, sloped] {$x:x$} (1)
        edge node [below, sloped] {$a:a$} (5)
      (1) edge node [above] {$a:a$} (2)
      (2) edge node [above] {$X:X$} (3)
      (3) edge node [above, sloped] {$i:i$} (4)
      (5) edge node [below] {$w:w$} (6)
      (6) edge node [below] {$r:r$} (7)
      (7) edge node [below, sloped] {$a:a$} (4)
      (3) edge [dashed] node [above, sloped] {$y:i+a=ya$} (5)
      ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: finite state transducer]

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your document is that you are trying to use the notation for the tool [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for a TikZ figure in a TeX document. However, the graphviz and tikz notations have nothing to do with each other.

I suggest that you start from [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/) for a finite-state machine in TikZ, and modify it according to your needs.

Tikz code is relative self-explaining when reading, so you should be able to understand the code in the example. For instance, in that example, the states are in red color. removing the statement `color=red` in the code changes that.

Comment: This is not really an answer, just a comment.

Comment: @pluton - In what sense is this not an answer? The OP asked for help on getting this started and didn't understand "how this works". The answer points out why the old approach did not work (or better: will not work) and how to get started. The OP never asked for a complete solution. Also, the graphviz code in his/her TeX document is not connected to the image given, so it is just an example.

Comment: @DCTLib. thanks for your answer. But How to draw these transitions?

Comment: @karu Look at the source code of the example from the TikZ gallery. There is a "\path (...) edge node {...} (...);" command. It draws edges. You will find examples in the Tikz documentation for how to modify paths (e.g., to make them dashed).

Comment: @ Downvoters, -1 is enough to say this answer needs work. @DCTLib, the convention in these cases (as I've seen) is to get the asker started with some sort of base to work from. Maybe not exactly what they asked for, but something to get them started. Importantly, such an example should be related and self-contained (i.e. no unnecessary links to external material). (Aside, I would hardly call Ti*k*Z self-explaining :-) it took me a long time to get used to reading it – let alone working with it.)

Comment: DCTLib, do not worry about my comment and the fact that your "answer" is not really appropriate for this site. It happened to me as well. Questions & Answers websites require very detailed answers, that's all. Continue participating.