# Trace / sample run of cascade of finite state transducer

Tags: automata

In Natural Language Processing (NLP) cascades of finite state transducers (FST) are used to model morphological processes. Now, I already know how to draw a graph illustration of an FST. See e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254278/adding-finite-state-transducer-fst-in-xelatex).

But I want to draw a figure which describes how an FST handles a specific input. Apologies for not knowing for sure how this type of figure is called. I recall it is either referred to as "trace" or "sample run". But you can find an illustration in [Jurafsky & Martin, Speech and Language Processing](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/xyzzy/JurafskyMartinEd2book.pdf) (Figure 3.20 on page 66 of this draft).

Does anyone know how to do that in latex?

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: What is so hard about the illustration you linked?  It's just boxes, lines, and labels, so if you can do the first one, it's just more of the same surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,fit,positioning,backgrounds,snakes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
letter/.style={draw,minimum width=0.7cm,minimum height=0.5cm,inner sep=0pt,anchor=center},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sf]
\node[letter] (lempty1) {~};
\node[letter,right=0cm of lempty1] (f1) {f};
\node[letter,right=0cm of f1] (o1) {o};
\node[letter,right=0cm of o1] (x1) {x};
\node[letter,right=0cm of x1] (N1) {+N};
\node[letter,right=0cm of N1] (P1) {+PL};
\node[letter,right=0cm of P1] (empty1) {~};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[fill=blue!20!white,-] ($(lempty1.south west)+(-5mm,0)$) 
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(lempty1.north west)+(-5mm,0)$)} -- ($(empty1.north east)+(5mm,0)$)
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(empty1.south east)+(5mm,0)$)} -- cycle;
% curly brackets see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345234/121799
\end{scope}
%
\node[letter,below=2cm of lempty1] (lempty2) {~};
\node[letter,right=0cm of lempty2] (f2) {f};
\node[letter,right=0cm of f2] (o2) {o};
\node[letter,right=0cm of o2] (x2) {x};
\node[letter,right=0cm of x2] (hat2) {\raisebox{3pt}{$\wedge$}};
\node[letter,right=0cm of hat2] (s2) {s};
\node[letter,right=0cm of s2] (hash2) {\#};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[fill=blue!20!white,-] ($(lempty2.south west)+(-5mm,0)$) 
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(lempty2.north west)+(-5mm,0)$)} -- ($(hash2.north east)+(5mm,0)$)
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(hash2.south east)+(5mm,0)$)} -- cycle;
% curly brackets see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345234/121799
\end{scope}
%
\node[letter,below=2cm of lempty2] (lempty3) {~};
\node[letter,right=0cm of lempty3] (f3) {f};
\node[letter,right=0cm of f3] (o3) {o};
\node[letter,right=0cm of o3] (x3) {x};
\node[letter,right=0cm of x3] (e3) {e};
\node[letter,right=0cm of e3] (s3) {s};
\node[letter,right=0cm of s3] (empty3) {~};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw[fill=blue!20!white,-] ($(lempty3.south west)+(-5mm,0)$) 
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(lempty3.north west)+(-5mm,0)$)} -- ($(empty3.north east)+(5mm,0)$)
decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}] 
{to ($(empty3.south east)+(5mm,0)$)} -- cycle;
% curly brackets see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345234/121799
\end{scope}
%
\draw[double distance=5mm,{Straight Barb[length=2pt,width=7mm,open].}-{.Straight Barb[length=2pt,width=7mm,open]}]
($(o1)!0.7!(x1)-(0,0.4cm)$) -- ($(o2)!0.7!(x2)+(0,0.4cm)$)
node[midway,draw,fill=white] {LEXICON-FST};
%
\draw[double distance=5mm,{Straight Barb[length=2pt,width=7mm,open].}-{.Straight Barb[length=2pt,width=7mm,open]}]
($(o2)!0.7!(x2)-(0,0.4cm)$) -- ($(o3)!0.7!(x3)+(0,0.4cm)$)
node[midway,draw,fill=white,minimum width=4cm] (box2) {\begin{tabular}{c}
{\tiny orthographic rules}\\
$\bullet~\bullet~\bullet$
\end{tabular}};
\node[draw,fill=white] at (box2.west) {FST$_1$};
\node[draw,fill=white] at (box2.east) {FST$_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]